# Update XML attribute value in document tree

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am not too sure why i cannot modify an attribute to my xml.  The code below i used to get the read the attributes from the XML.  Pulls the attributes without any issues.

```
        document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
        NodeList sessionNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("session");
        if (sessionNodelist.getLength() > 0)
        {
            Element sessionElement = (Element) sessionNodelist.item(0);
            String timeout = sessionElement.getAttribute("timeout");
            String warning = sessionElement.getAttribute("warning");
        }
```

Now when i go to set them, it doesn't work and I am not too sure why.  The code is below.  it's the exact same code i used to pull the atribles, but instead of the getAttribute i used setAttribute which takes two parameters.   setAttribute(String name, String Value).

```
        document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
        NodeList sessionNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("session");
        if (sessionNodelist.getLength() > 0)
        {
            Element sessionElement = (Element) sessionNodelist.item(0);
            sessionElement.setAttribute("timeout","12");
            sessionElement.setAttribute("warning", "10");
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is expected here? The element attributes are being changed. Do you want to save them back in the XML?

Comment: Yes, my UI allows users to change the value, so I am setting the new value in the xml.

Comment: How are you verifying that the attributes were or were not changed?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052871/add-new-attributes-to-an-existing-xml-node-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the document tree back to the XML file. See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html) for how to write a DOM tree to a file.

You would use a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` to write the object into the file as follows:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: Last question, for somereason when i go to write the file path it doesn't like the fact that there is a space within program files.  Any way to get around this?  I am using escape chars E.g "C:\\Progarm Files\\test.xml"